# Output of SVM classification always gives same label when using Leave-One-Out cross-validation

Tags: cross-validation, svm

I've trained a SVM in a slightly unbalanced dataset (class '0' frequency is 1.38 times higher than class '1') so I was using a StratifiedKFold cross-validation to measure my classifier's performance.
As my dataset is very small, I wanted to to use Leave-One-Out. But, as soon as I tried it, I noticied that something was wrong:

StratifiedKFold (k=5):

```
Precision: 0.84 (std: 0.13)
Accuracy: 0.83 (std: 0.10)
```

Leave-One-Out:

```
Precision: 0.00 (std: 0.00)
Accuracy: 0.57 (std: 0.50)
```

A quick inspection revealed to me that this happened because the classifier always gave the same label to the validation samples (class 0). The same happened when I used Gradient Boost classification method.